# Redis latency showing better results in weaker hardware. What could be the cause?

Tags: redis

I'm running the following command to test latency across different servers and found that weaker hardware is performing better than stronger hardware.

`redis-cli --latency -h '127.0.0.1' -p '6379'`

**Results:**

E3-1270 @ 3.80GHz - Debian 9 - Memory 2400MHz - Latency: ~0.26ms

E5-405 @ 2.00GHz - Debian 7 - Memory 664MHz - Latency: ~0.06ms

E5-2620 @ 2.10GHz - Debian 9 - Memory 2400MHz - Latency: ~0.16ms

E5-2420 @ 1.90GHz - Debian 7 - Memory 800MHz - Latency: ~0.21ms

I strongly believed that ordering a E3-1270 @ 3.80GHz would improve our Redis latency but the results were disappointing.

- All servers have clean OS installed and only critical services running. All other services that could be competing for CPU were disabled before running the tests.
- All tests were done using Docker and not using Docker and could come to the conclusion both ways showed exactly the same results.

What could be impacting the Redis performance in the stronger servers?

Thanks,

Comment: I presume you have read this carefully https://redis.io/topics/latency

Comment: Yes, I did and I'm still not able to detect the latency difference between these servers. E3-1270 is a better processor than E5-405, almost 2 times better frequency, memory with 4 times better frequency and still performing 4 times worst than E5-405.